# Create/Modify Survey - API v3

Tags: surveymonkey

I have used V2 of the Survey Monkey API to get details on collectors and surveys. I am now interested in learning how to use the V3 API to Create/Modify surveys. I hope some useful tips from other users, would help me out, as I am relatively new to the API. I will be using Python.

Specifically, my use case is that I want to use a base survey as a template, and modify the answer options per recipient. Here is an example:

Recipient A would get:

Q1. On a scale of 1 (least) to 5 (most), how much do you like eating:

a. Burgers
b. Pizza
c. Hotdogs

Q2. On a scale of 1 (rarely) to 5 (very), in a typical week, how often do you eat:

a. Burgers
b. Pizza
c. Hotdogs

While recipient B would get

Q1. On a scale of 1 (least) to 5 (most), how much do you like eating:

a. Fried chicken
b. French fries
c. Tacos

Q2. On a scale of 1 (rarely) to 5 (very), in a typical week, how often do you eat:

a. Fried chicken
b. French fries
c. Tacos

How do I create the API that reads in the various answer options.

I also plan to use pandas to load the table of answer options per recipient, and want to find out how to pipe the answer options into the API - would it be through a conversion into JSON? Have read the documentation, but it's not always obvious what needs to be done (to a newbie).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't branching logic available to show/hide answer options. If you were sending the survey to one recipient at a time, and you really wanted to have one question with modified answer options you could theoretically do something like this:

```
POST /v3/surveys/<id>/pages/<id>/questions

{
  "family": "matrix",
  "subtype": "rating",
  "answers": {
    "rows": [
      {
        "text": "Burgers",
        "visible": true,
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "text": "Pizza",
        "visible": true,
        "position": 2
      },
      {
        "text": "Hotdogs",
        "visible": true,
        "position": 3
      },
      {
        "text": "Fried chicken",
        "visible": false,
        "position": 4
      },

      {
        "text": "French fries",
        "visible": false,
        "position": 5
      },

      {
        "text": "Tacos",
        "visible": false,
        "position": 6
      }
    ],
    "choices": [
      {
        "text": "1",
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "text": "2",
        "position": 2
      },
      {
        "text": "3",
        "position": 3
      },
      {
        "text": "4",
        "position": 4
      },
      {
        "text": "5",
        "position": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  "headings": [
    {
      "heading": "On a scale of 1 (least) to 5 (most), how much do you like eating:"
    }
  ],
  "forced_ranking": false
}
```

And then patch `visible` on the answer options between true and false for each recipient, that way you can analyse on the same question. But that's not really ideal as this changes the survey for everyone taking it limiting you to one recipient taking the survey at a time.

Given you are planning on moving the data to pandas anyways, why not just separate into four different questions? Then just use [advanced branching](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Advanced-Branching-Rules) to hide/show questions based on a custom value on the recipient. That way you can have a rule that's something like:

```
if contact.custom1 is exactly "fried" then hide question 1 and show question 2
```

Then you can [export all your data](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Exports) or fetch your responses through the API

```
GET /v3/surveys/<id>/responses/bulk
```

Which will give you a JSON of all the responses which you can move to pandas. There may be other ways to do what you'd like but given the available functionality; this is a couple examples that may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I plan to use an email collector. The survey however will have multiple answer combinations, each combination unique to a recipient - could advanched branching work? The main task I want to achieve here is the automated population of the answer options - that is a crucial part of the puzzle that I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I should add there are about a thousand recipients each with a unique combination (food choices vary by country). It is not possible to provide a list of answer options to pick from and branch from there as the business requirement is to use the answer options identified prior. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes so you could add recipients to an email collector with a field specifying their country for example, and then use advanced branching to show/hide questions based on that field. You can maybe also have a first page that is pre-filled based on the recipient and then carry forward responses (http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Carry-Forward). If you don't know which questions to show until the recipient answers a previous question (e.g. which country do you live in?) then you can do advanced branching based on the response to that. Sorry if Im not fully understanding your scenario!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the additional feedback. After looking at the Advanced Branching help file, it still sounds like I would still have to manually enter the answer options for all the 1000+ survey recipients, which is what I was hoping to automate through the API. I do not need to automate the creation of collector or assigning the email recipients to the collector. I just need to automate the loading of the variable answer options to the base question template, or automate the entire survey creation process (which means loading both the fixed question set and variable answer options)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you can't set branching rules through the API (at least yet). One last possibility I can think of is writing out the branching rule as logic (ex: `contact.custom1 = "fried" => HIDE Q2`). There's an advanced branching rule language you can use (ask support for the flag on your account) and then you can potentially automate the build of all the rules and copy/paste it in the advanced branching wizard. Otherwise, I'm not quite sure the best way to do it, if you figure out something that works well with the API please let me know!